# Converting List[Map[String, Any]] to Option[com.google.protobuf.struct.Struct] using Scalapb

Tags: scala, grpc, scalapb

I am trying to convert `List[Map[String, Any]` to `Option[com.google.protobuf.struct.Struct]` using `Scalapb`:

Proto:

```
message IOTDecodeRequest {
  string id = 1;
  string user_id = 2;
  bytes raw_data = 3;
}

message DecodeResult {
  google.protobuf.Struct decoded = 1;
}
```

I need to store:

```
 val rawdata: List[Map[String, Any]] =
   List(
     Map("Userid" -> 860267, "height " -> 0.062),
     Map("userid" -> 860268, "height " -> 0.062)
   )
```

into `DecodeResult` using Scala.

How can I do the conversion?

Comment: You should also provide your input!

Comment: And avoid using `Any`. It can hold: primitives, Unit (void), nulls, and virtually any objects: normal classes, sealed traits, anonymous classes. It is virtually impossible tell what you have there. If raw data are bytes, then I suggest storing there something which represents bytes.

Comment: input is bytes which i will decode and the result will be in the form of List[Map[string,Any]],  which is for example : List(
     Map("Userid" -> 860267, "height " -> 0.062),
     Map("userid" -> 860268, "height " -> 0.062)
   )